# How to make last element in a series of wrapped inline-block elements fill the available horizontal space?

Tags: css

I have an element which will contain an unspecified number of inline-block elements which may wrap if there are enough elements.

I want the last element to fill the remaining space on the line. How can this be accomplished?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Example HTML

```
<div class="tags">
  <span class="tags__item">First Tag</span>
  <span class="tags__item">Another One</span>
  <span class="tags__item">Long Tag Name Here</span>
  <span class="tags__item">Last tag should fill</span>
</div>
```

Example CSS

```
.tags { border: solid 1px #000; padding: 0; }
.tags__item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background: #eee;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}
.tags__item:last-child {
  background: #fff;
  border: dashed 1px #eee;
}
```

### Attempt #1 (doesn't work)

One answer (which was deleted) mentioned trying table-cell layout like this..

```
.tags {
  border: solid 1px #000; 
  display: table-row;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tags__item {
  display:table-cell;
  width:auto;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background: #eee;
}
.tags__item:last-child {
  background: #fff;
  border: dashed 1px #ccc;
  width:99%
}
```

This solution works reasonably well for a single line. However, it doesn't allow wrapping.  http://cdpn.io/omFuy

### Attempt #2 (doesn't work)

Someone else linked to another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220142/is-it-possible-for-inline-block-element-to-auto-fill-the-available-width) as a possible solution.

```
.tags {
  border: solid 1px #000; 
}
.tags__item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background: #eee;
}
.tags__item:last-child {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border: dashed 1px #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}
.tags__item:last-child::after {
  clear:both;
}
```

But it doesn't work. [See my implementation](http://codepen.io/jessegavin/pen/oEyIF).

Comment: @Milche: those are the "if this question gets a working answer, that'd be awesome and I can use it myself!" votes (because it would be, if it were at all possible without `table` emulation).

Comment: @MilchePatern it's a good question that I think would benefit others (and myself), and any attempt is so simple and obvious that I think it would be silly to put failed code into it.

Comment: Fully related : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=make+an+inline-block+element+fill+available+space

Comment: Take a look at the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220142/is-it-possible-for-inline-block-element-to-auto-fill-the-available-width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For browsers that support it, the natural solution is to use the [flexible layout module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/), aka flexbox—this is exactly the sort of scenario it is intended for. Here are the bare essentials:

**[Demo on Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/7585471)**

```css
.tags {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tags__item:last-child {
    flex: auto;
}
```

The (not insignificant) downside to this approach is the [lack of browser support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) and the attendant mess of prefixes and fallbacks if you need to support older browsers. As suggested by [Rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242389/rafaelcastrocouto) in the comments, this [CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) outlines the required prefixes and the legacy syntax.

Comment: You are a king among mortal men! Thanks! Works perfectly!

Comment: @jessegavin Aw, shucks! :) One word of advice, though: support for flexbox is far from perfect! This works like a charm in very modern browsers, but you'll need to add quite a few prefixes and fallbacks before it plays nice in older UAs.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the best solution ... but I just did not resisted to try a javascript solution.

http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/morlb

Still need to check for "line-breaks", but it can be useful since jQuery probably turns this cross browser.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I am seeing some odd behavior when adding additional `<span>` elements. It seems to work really nicely for the exact number of spans you have.

Comment: Yes it does happens ... there are still lots of improvements in order to make it a good solution ... you should go for a lib like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996/what-is-the-best-css-grid-framework

Comment: Would a CSS framework solve this particular problem? If so, which one? How does it solve it?  I use bootstrap, but it doesn't have anything built in which addresses this.

Comment: You could go for http://purecss.io/ ... I never used but seens pretty good ... and it's all just css ... you can't go wrong!